# Matrices are not aligned while dot product with DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dot-product

```
butter_prices
```

```
    Almond butter   Peanut butter   Cashew butter
Price   10  8   12
```

```
weekly_sales
```

```
    Almonds butter  Peanut butter   Cashew butter
Mon 12  15  0
Tues    3   3   7
Wed 9   19  18
Thurs   4   6   12
Fri 1   6   7
```

Now, while doing

```
butter_prices.shape, weekly_sales.shape
```

```
((1, 3), (5, 3))
```

now the error shows while calculating

```
butter_prices.dot(weekly_sales.T)
```

`ValueError: matrices are not aligned`

Expected the Dot product of two

Comment: What's your expected outpu?

Comment: does `weekly_sales @ butter_prices.T` give the right output?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `values`

```
out = weekly_sales.dot(butter_prices.iloc[0].values)
out
Mon      240
Tues     138
Wed      458
Thurs    232
Fri      142
dtype: int64
```

Or align the name

```
butter_prices.columns = weekly_sales.columns
butter_prices.dot(weekly_sales.T)
       Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri
Price  240   138  458    232  142
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in the column name `Almonds butter` -> `Almond butter`:

```py
weekly_sales = weekly_sales.rename(columns={"Almonds butter": "Almond butter"})
print(butter_prices.dot(weekly_sales.T))
```

Prints:

```
       Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri
Price  240   138  458    232  142
```